# Retrieve email ids from multiple full Email Address using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL-server
Am trying to retrieve email id from list of full email addresses

Example 
Input

```
"ABCD"<abcd@gmail.com>;"TEST" <test@outlook.com>;
```

Needed output

```
abcd@gmail.com,test@outlook.com
```

i have tried the below query but it is giving only one email id not all.Some help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN to_address LIKE '%<%'
             THEN SUBSTRING(to_address, CHARINDEX('<',to_address)+1, CHARINDEX('>',to_address) - CHARINDEX('<',to_address)-1)
             ELSE to_address
        END) AS ToAddress
from test
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: sql-server, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Using SQL-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `string_split()`:

```
select replace(stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('<', s.value), ''), '>', '')
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.list, ';') s
```

If you want to re-concatenate them:

```
select s.emails
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(replace(stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('<', s.value), ''), '>', ''), ';') as email
      from string_split(t.list, ';') s
     ) s;
```

EDIT:

Another approach which works with earlier versions of SQL Server is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as email,
             convert(varchar(max), emails) as rest,
             convert(varchar(max), '') as output_emails, 0 as lev
      from (values ('"ABCD"<abcd@gmail.com>;"TEST" <test@outlook.com>; ')
           ) v(emails)
      union all
      select replace(stuff(v.el, 1, charindex('<', v.el), ''), '>;', ''),
             stuff(rest, 1, charindex(';', rest), ''),
             concat(output_emails,
                    replace(stuff(v.el, 1, charindex('<', v.el), ''), '>;', ''),
                    ';'),
             lev + 1
      from cte cross apply
           (values (left(rest, charindex(';', rest)))) v(el) 
      where rest <> '' and lev < 5
     )
select output_emails
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41e66c151614656e721af7f7897946b5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: getting error 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function' and invalid object name 'string_split'

Comment: @Ayesha . . . These are available starting in SQL Server 2017 -- which was released three years ago now, so it is not really that "new".  In older versions you need to take more complex approaches.

Comment: we are using ms SQL server 2014 which is throwing error in fiddle like "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "output_emails" of recursive query "cte"."

Comment: @Ayesha . . . I've included a DB fiddle.  This issue doesn't change between the versions.  You can just convert the values in the anchor portion to `varchar(max)` (or `nvarchar(max)` if appropriate).  I think the db<>fiddle illustrates that the code works.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff....i used CAST in initial query..it worked                                                    CAST(null as varchar(max)) as email,
CAST(emails as varchar(max)) as rest,
CAST('' as nvarchar(max)) as output_emails